# How to assign tasks

Tags: algorithm

Here is the scene.
There are some tasks, and some machines for running these tasks. Each machine can run specific task. But the number of tasks each machine can run is **limited** by their hardware(we can assume that there are some working slots in each machine).Suppose once a task is assigned to a machine, it will run for a infinite long time and cannot be preempted, so these is no need to consider using one slot for different tasks in turn.

For example, there are tasks marked as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and two machine A and B. The tasks and the number of tasks each machine can run is showed as follow:
`A [1, 2, 3] (2)`
`B [2, 4]    (1)`
Numbers in the square brackets represent tasks the machine can run, and the number in the parentheses behind represent the number of tasks the machine can run.

Now the problem is: How to assign these tasks to **maximize** the number of tasks being assigned ? Does any algorithm can solves this problem?

Thank you (-:

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general algorithms and should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question based on the given information. What is missing is the "costs" of executing a task. If there is no information about _how long a task takes_ to be processed on a system then it is not possible to decide which is the most efficient schedule.

Comment: Did you try a maximum flow algorithm on the bipartite graph formed by your machines and tasks (edge if the machine can run the task)?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this, for instance.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/